# Fixed element positioning relative to its parent

Tags: html, css

I have an element that gets `position: fixed` while dragging. This element is inside a modal that is a direct child of the `body` element.

On the image below, the modal is gray, the rest of the body is black, and the button is blue. When I add the following styles to the button:

```
position: fixed;
top: xxxpx;
left: -100px;
```

It positions the button relative to the modal, not the viewport. Is that even possible that an element with `position: fixed` be positioned relative to something but the viewport? It acts like an absolutely positioned element instead.

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please show us enough code so that we can get the context. In particular, what styling is applied to its parent?

Comment: @AHaworth, I don't want to insert the whole code here, but I think the important parts are: `<div style="position: fixed; ..."><div style="transform: translate(0, 0); ..."><button style="position: fixed; ... ">button</button></div></div>`. This looks like a bug because of the `transform` being applied to the parent element? I thought `position: fixed` elements being relative to the viewport is an axiom.

Comment: actually it  is positioned relative to body, **100px** far from left side, and **xxxpx** from top. it will stay there. if you want to make it relative to the modal change fixed to absolute

Comment: did you added transform-origin property ?

Comment: @Anirudhsanthosh, no. If it was placed correctly it would be at the left edge of the black space. The black space is ~1500px on my screen. Also mind it says minus 100px.

Comment: here is an example to show you how it can behave from the viewport or its parent https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYWXdqo . Without your code it is unclear what is your issue. one or the other ? from moz spec : *fixed
    The element is removed from the normal document flow,.... It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, **except** when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property....*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'normally' position fixed fixes relative to the viewport.

But there are exceptions. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms Spec), in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block. (Note that there are browser inconsistencies with perspective and filter contributing to containing block formation.) Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

Here's a simple example:

```css
body {}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  transform: scale(1);
  width: 50vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background: black;
  rfilter: blur(1);
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Notice that the blue child element is placed at the top left of its parent. Its parent has a transform - and as it's scale(1) we might assume it doesn't do much. But it does create the parent as the containing block.

I think your problem is the transform on the parent.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. Thanks for the answer! I know that's a separate question, but any way to bypass this while keeping the transforms and fixed position?

Comment: I guess we'd need to know more about what was actually wanted - e.g. what the transform was for and why the child has to be in that parent, whether the parent has to be positioned etc.

Comment: I am afraid this would lead to unnecessary complexity. I will try to sort this out on my own now. Thanks again!

Comment: That really is an odd feature. Why would a `transform: translateX(1px)` should create a new positioning context?